# Create python package

Tags: python, package

I created a py file called orderbook.py which contains a class called OrderbookLoader. Everything is in a directory called `loaders`. I added that path to the ipythonpath, so the following: `/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/research/data_manager/loaders`
In my directory I have multiple other files as well:
[image]

But when I go my root directory and try the following: 
`from loaders.orderbook import OrderbookLoader` it throws the following error message: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'loaders.orderbook'; 'loaders' is not a package`

But I can do the following:
`from loaders import OrderbookLoader` which is a class from the `loaders.py` file. Do you have any idea what I did wrong? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with interactions between your work directory (not specified in your question), the Python path (also not specified), and the files in the supposed package directory.

To make a directory a package, you should:

- Ensure that is resides directly a directory that is in the Python path (`sys.path`).
- Ensure that it includes a file named `__init__.py` (which you did). That file may be empty, or contain legal Python code.

What is probably happening here is that you made the directory `loaders`, itself, part of the Python path. If you added its parent directory (as you should have), it was probably placed after `loaders`. What happens next is that when Python tries to import `loaders`, it imports the file `loaders.py` inside the `loaders` directory, before finding the `loaders`package directory inside its parent. This means that `loaders`, specified to the import mechanism, refers to the module, rather than the package, hence the results of your two `import` attempts.

This placement of a module inside a package, both with the same name, is not a good idea, as it may lead to the situation you encounter here.